# How to perform 2D image rotation by FFT based image translation using matlab?

Tags: image-processing, fft, ifft, computer-graphics

I am studying rotation using 3 translations as described in this [scientific paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.190.4473&rep=rep1&type=pdf). According to the authors , it is possible to decompose a rotation into 3 shear translations which will be implemented in the frequency domain by FFT according to time-frequency shifting theorems.

For example the first translation is obtained as in equation (13) by doing the following operation for every pixel considering that the horizental coordinate x is variable and the vertical coordinate y is fixed:

Gx(x,y)=FFT-1(exp(-2*pi*a*u*y)*FFT(f(x,y)) where f is the value of the pixel x,y , a is a constant for the translation and FFT-1 is the inverse fourrier transform and u is x mapped into the frequency domain.

To code this transformation, one should think as follow: 
We have to compute  Gx by changing the range of U from -M/(2*M) to (M/2*M) and by iterating y from 1 to N.

Surprisingly, the suggested implementation doesn't follow the procedure above:
Can somebody develop further why the implementation is as follow.

```
close all;
clear all;
I = double(imread('Put image here'))/255;
%imshow(I)
I=rgb2gray(I);
facteur=4;
[M, N, s] = size (I); 


temp=ones(2*M,2*N);
temp(floor(M/2):floor(M/2)+M-1,floor(N/2):floor(N/2)+N-1)=I(:,:);
I=temp; clear temp;
imshow(I)
[M N s]=size(I)
 teta=pi/8;
a=tan(teta/2)
b=-sin(teta)

 Nx = ifftshift(-fix(M/2):ceil(M/2)-1); 
 Ny = ifftshift(-fix(N/2):ceil(N/2)-1);
 Ix=zeros(length(Nx),length(Ny));
 for k=1:M
   Ix(k,:)=(ifft(fft(I(k,:)).*exp(-2*i*pi*(k-floor(M/2))*Ny*a/N)));
 end
 %imshow(Ix);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is the completed code that yields the expected result:

```
close all; clear all; clc;

I = double(imread('Cameraman.tif'))/255;
figure,imshow(I)

[M, N, s] = size (I); 

temp=ones(2*M,2*N);
temp(floor(M/2):floor(M/2)+M-1,floor(N/2):floor(N/2)+N-1)=I;
I=temp; clear temp;

figure,imshow(I)
[M N s]=size(I)
teta = pi/3;
a = tan(teta/2)
b = -sin(teta)

 Nx = ifftshift(-fix(M/2):ceil(M/2)-1); 
 Ny = ifftshift(-fix(N/2):ceil(N/2)-1);
 Ix=zeros(length(Nx),length(Ny));
 for k=1:M
   Ix(k,:)=real(ifft(fft(I(k,:)).*exp(-2*i*pi*(k-floor(M/2))*Ny*a/N)));
 end

 Iy = zeros(size(Ix));
 for k=1:M
   Iy(:,k)=real(ifft(fft(Ix(:,k)).*exp(2*i*pi*(k-floor(M/2))*Ny*b/N)'));
 end

 If = zeros(size(Iy));
 for k=1:M
   If(k,:)=real(ifft(fft(Iy(k,:)).*exp(-2*i*pi*(k-floor(M/2))*Ny*a/N)));
 end

 figure,imshow(Ix);
 figure,imshow(Iy);
 figure,imshow(If);
```

So this works as expected from a 2D rotation about z-axis. The paper argues that this is a **fast** and accurate method, but I doubt that, as a simple 2D **rotation** could easily be implemented using raw trigonometric computations and a bilinear interpolation (or bicubic if a sharper result is desired) other than forward and inverse FFTs.

I can say that the method is **slow** (on matlab, it can be further vectorized however). On the other hand the perceptual quality of the resulting rotated image is fairly **good** except some little ringing artefacts towards the edges.

I suggest you the ch-5 of *Principles of Computer Graphics* 2E by FOLEY for further understanding of the mathematics used in these algorithms and applications.

Comment: @damdam092 You have interesting problems. Are you working on an image processing application ?